# Displaying a string into a listview

Tags: android, json, string, listview

I successfully parsed data from this [website here](http://ec2-54-213-155-95.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/notices.php). After writing a few codes, I get a string in which I would like to display into a ListView. Basically, I want to display the whole array from the website into a ListView.

```
DefaultHttpClient   httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://ec2-54-213-155-95.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/notices.php");
// Depends on your web service
httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = null;
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        inputStream = entity.getContent();
        // json is UTF-8 by default
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        // Oops
    }
    finally {
        try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
    }

    try {
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jObject.getJSONArray("notices");        
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            String arrayString = jsonArray.getString(i);
            Log.d("notices", arrayString); 
            ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am thinking of using arrayAdapter but I am not to sure of how to use it!

Answer (score 4):

First decide whether you want to store your data in ArrayList or the Database before showing it in ListView. For ArrayList to ListView you will need ArrayAdapter and from database to ListView you will need CursorAdapter.
In ArrayList if you only have only TextView then you can use Simple ArrayAdapter else if there are multiple TextViews or more components then go for Custom ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SimpleArrayAdapter as follows :-

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            String arrayString = jsonArray.getString(i);
            Log.d("notices", arrayString); 
          list .add(arrayString);


    }


// and after filling this array list you can set this adapter to you list as 
ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
 final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listView1 .setAdapter(adapter)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show your data in listview then u can use following code:

```
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter;
     ListView listView1 ;

    // Initialize array adapter.

   mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.array_layout);
    listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    // Rest of your code...
    //
    //  

 try {
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jObject.getJSONArray("notices");        
            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                String arrayString = jsonArray.getString(i);
                   mArrayAdapter.add(arrayString) ;

                Log.d("notices", arrayString); 
                }
               listView1.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**array_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:padding="5dp"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the data using `ArrayList<String>` and `StableArrayAdapter` as below:

> ```
>     ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1); 
>      JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
>     JSONArray jsonArray = jObject.getJSONArray("notices");   
>      final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
>      for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; ++i) 
>        {
>            String arrayString = jsonArray.getString(i);
>             Log.d("notices", arrayString); 
>            list.add(arrayString);
>      }
>     final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
>     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
>     listview1.setAdapter(adapter);
> ```

**StableArrayAdapter class**

> ```
>    private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
>          HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
>    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
>            List<String> objects) {
>          super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
>         for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
>           mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
>      }
>   }
> @Override
> public long getItemId(int position) {
>   String item = getItem(position);
>   return mIdMap.get(item);
> }
> @Override
> public boolean hasStableIds() {
>   return true;
> }
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

You may have got the answer till now but still it may help others.
I did it this way and it works great.

I made an xml recco_list file with 4 text views in.

Declare these.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
ListView list;
```

Getting into array

```
      for(int i = 0; i < RECCO_ARRAY.length(); i++) {
        try {

            JSONObject recco = RECCO_ARRAY.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject program = recco.getJSONObject("program");
            JSONObject outlet = recco.getJSONObject("outlet");
            String normalized_weight = recco.getString("normalized_weight");
            String distance = recco.getString("distance");
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String program_name = program.getString("name");
            String outlet_basics = outlet.getString("basics");
            String outlet_name = new JSONObject(outlet_basics).getString("name");
            map.put("program_name", program_name);
            map.put("outlet_name", outlet_name);
            map.put("normalized_weight", normalized_weight);
            map.put("distance", distance);

            oslist.add(map);
            list= (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recco_list);
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), oslist, 
                    R.layout.recco_list_view, new String[] {"program_name","outlet_name", "normalized_weight", "distance"}, 
                    new int[]{R.id.program_name,R.id.outlet_name, R.id.normalized_weight, R.id.distance});
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```